# App IOS com Intel XDK em windows

Tags: ios, mobile, intel-xdk, apple

Quero publicar um APP que fiz na Apple Store. A versão do mesmo para android já está rodando e OK. Minha dúvida é se, mesmo eu não tendo um MAC, conseguirei publicar o aplicativo compilado no windows para IOS sem problemas? Fiquei com medo de fazer a assinatura de desenvolvedor apple e me deparar no futuro com a impossibilidade de publicação por não ter um MAC. Alguém já publicou apps feitos no windows na apple store ?

Obrigado pela atenção de todos =D

Answer (score 0):

Eu já publiquei app para ios feito no windows. Você consegue gerar o arquivo .ipa mas o problema esta em mandar para o itunnes. Precisei usar o macinclound para acessar um Mac virtual e enviar meu arquivo para o itunnes o Application Loader. Não consegui de forma nenhuma enviar o arquivo para o itunnes direto pelo windows, só pelo http://www.macincloud.com mesmo. Ele cobra 1 dolar a hora mas para criar a conta você tem que pagar 30 horas. Caso consigo emular um mac no windows ou algo do tipo você deve conseguir. Se tiver um conhecido com um mac é melhor ainda.